# Ajax HtmlCommand not working on form field in a field group

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I've added a custom ajax callback to a field that I'm trying to update the value of. The Field I'm updating is inside a field group and instead of updating the field it just empties the html.

The form item with the ajax callback

```
$form['sku'] = [
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#title' => $this->t('SKU'),
  '#target_type' => 'node',
  '#selection_handler' => 'views',
  '#selection_settings' => [
    'view' => [
      'view_name' => 'parts_reference',
      'display_name' => 'entity_reference_1',
      'arguments' => []
    ],
    'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS'
  ],
  '#weight' => '0',
  '#size' => '200',
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::oeRefAjaxCallback',
    // don't forget :: when calling a class method.
    //'callback' => [$this, 'myAjaxCallback'], //alternative notation
    'disable-refocus' => FALSE,
    // Or TRUE to prevent re-focusing on the triggering element.
    'event' => 'change',
    // This element is updated with this AJAX callback.
    'progress' => [
      'type' => 'throbber',
      'message' => $this->t('Verifying entry...'),
    ],
  ]
];
```

The form item that is to be updated

```
$form['item_specifics_type'] = [
  '#title' => 'Type',
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#value' => '',
  '#size' => '60',
  '#group' => 'fieldset_item_specifics',
  '#prefix' => '<div id="item-specific-type-wrapper">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>'
];
```

--

```
$response = new AjaxResponse();
$response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#item-specific-type-wrapper', $form['item_specifics_type']));
return $response;
```

If I remove the group key from the field array so that the field is not in the fieldset then the ajax command replaces the field with the correct html as expected.

Comment: Your response needs to have the group key.`$form['the_group_key']['item_specifics_type']));`

Comment: How do I add the form key and the ajax response?

Comment: In your code, type it in the `$response->addCommand` line, replace `$form['item_specifics_type']));` with my first comment.